# PHP - Passing variables from one page to another

Tags: php, file, session, variables

I am trying to pass on the value of one variable from one PHP page to another PHP page, but for some reason, it's not working..

Here's my code for phpOne.php:

```
<?php
    $x = 100;
    $_SESSION['sessionVar'] = $x;
    echo "$x";
?>
```

And here's my code for phpTwo.php:

```
<?php
$x = $_SESSION['sessionVar'];
echo "$x";
?>
```

Thanks in-advance!
Tom!

Comment: When you say its not working, what isn't? Elaborate.. Any error messages?

Comment: Do you have `session_start()` in those pages, too?

Comment: As andrewsi said, you have to use session_start() in every page, that uses the $_SESSION variable. Put it on the first line after <?php. Basically before any output.

Comment: No, I didn't. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call    session_start(); on both pages.

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
session_start();
```

to start up your session. You need to add this on all pages that need to access the $_SESSION[] variables, otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $x = 100;
  $_SESSION['sessionVar'] = $x;
  echo "$x";
?>


<?php
  session_start();
  $x = $_SESSION['sessionVar'];
  echo "$x";
?>
```

You have to init `session_start()` to make use of the session variables.

Answer (score 2):

Everyone is right. Session variables are stored in the server with a reference key. The key(known as PHP SESSION ID) is stored in the server as well as the browser cookie. Each time the browser sends the key to the server. If the server gets a session_start() without a key then it initiates a new session. Whereas if the browser page has the key then it restores the session. Which is why it becomes essential that you call the session_start() in both pages. I hope this clears it up!! Good luck

Read this for deeper explanation (if you want) : http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php