# I'm having trouble passing variables from one php file to another

Tags: php, xml, json, php-parser

I'm trying to pass the variables data from php1.php to php2.php. 
this is what I'm trying to do:

I'm using php to load a xml(not validated with feedvalidator.org) from a url, and then to pass the variables data to another php2.php(this one creates a json file). I'm not using the php function to convert xml to json because I'm changing the structure.
Both files work great separately : php1.php load correctly the xml and php2.php creates the json structure i want, my problem is : i can't pass the variables data from php1.php to php2.php.
I've already tried this:
[PHP - Passing variables from one page to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16523703/php-passing-variables-from-one-page-to-another?rq=1)
and
[How to pass variables from one php page to another without form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252418/how-to-pass-variables-from-one-php-page-to-another-without-form?rq=1)
and i haven't been able to get the code working.

I'm trying to pass : $lbd, $title, $guid, $author, $description

-thanks.

this is my code :

php1.php

```
$html = "";
$url = "http://www.conciencia.net/rss.aspx";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

$channel_title = $xml->channel->title;
$channel_link = $xml->channel->link;
$managingEditor = $xml->channel->managingEditor;
$channel_description = $xml->channel->description;
$lbd = $xml->channel->lastBuildDate;

$html .= "<br/>$channel_title";
$html .= "<br/>$channel_link";
$html .= "<br/>$managingEditor";
$html .= "<br/>$lbd";
$html .= "<br/>$channel_description";

for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++){

    $pubDate = $xml->channel->item[$i]->pubDate;
$title = $xml->channel->item[$i]->title;
$link = $xml->channel->item[$i]->link;
    $guid = $xml->channel->item[$i]->guid;
    $author = $xml->channel->item[$i]->author;
$description = $xml->channel->item[$i]->description;


    $html .= "<br/>$pubDate";     
$html .= "<a href='$link'><h3>$title</h3></a>";
    $html .= "$link";
    $html .= "<br/>$guid";
    $html .= "<br/>$author";
$html .= "<br/>$description";


}

echo $html;
?>
```

php2.php

```
$feeds['conciencia'] = array(
 'channel' => array(
     'title' =>"Un Mensaje a la Conciencia", 'link' =>"www.conciencia.net", 'managingEditor'  =>"Hermano Pablo y Carlos Rey", 'description' => "Populares programas de 4 minutos que comienzan     con una anécdota o historia y terminan con una aplicación moral y espiritual. Se han transmitido de lunes a sábado durante más de 40 años. Actualmente se difunden más de 4 mil veces al día en 30 países en la radio, la televisión y la prensa, y ahora via Internet en Conciencia.net.", 'lastBuildDate' => "$lbd", 'language' => "es-ES", 'copyright' => "\u00a9 2015 Asociaci\u00f3n Hermano Pablo",    'item' => array(  
            array(  
                'title' => "$title", 'link' => "$link", 'guid' => "$guid", 'author' => "$author", 'description' => "$description", 'enclosure' => array(
            array( '@attributes' => array( 'url' =>"$url", 'length' => "$length", 'type' => "$type")
            )
            ) 
            )
        )
)
);

echo json_encode($feeds);

?>
```

Comment: What variable to you with to pass? There's no $feeds in the first file!

Comment: I've updated my question.the variables I'm trying to pass are posted now.

Comment: you don't "pass variables" between scripts. each script is executed separately as each http reqeust comes in, and there is NO shared code between any two+ php processes. If you want data from one script to show up in another, you'll have to pass it somehow. e.g sessions, query parameters, form fields, etc...

Comment: @Marc B and how can do that with sessions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add session_start(); at the beginning of each file, before echoing anything. Then at the end of  file 1, add this:

```
$_SESSION['lbd'] = $lbd;
$_SESSION['title'] = $title;
$_SESSION['guid'] = $guid;
$_SESSION['author'] = $author;
$_SESSION['description'] = $description;
```

and then, in the second one, add:

```
$lbd = $_SESSION['lbd'];
$title = $_SESSION['title'];
$guid = $_SESSION['guid'];
$author = $_SESSION['author'];
$description = $_SESSION['description'];
```

The variables should be available now.

Comment: thanks @motanelu I've tried that and i haven't get the variables yet.